# Why doesn't \settoheight of \parbox work?

Tags: boxes, calculations, lengths

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{printlen}

\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newlength{\fooboxheight}

\savebox{\foobox}{
    \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{Line 1\\Line 2\\Line 3\\Line 4}
}
\settoheight{\fooboxheight}{\usebox{\foobox}}

\begin{document}

\usebox{\foobox}


Address box height: \printlength{\fooboxheight} \uselengthunit{mm} \printlength{\fooboxheight}

\end{document}
```

`\fooboxheight` is 7pt / 2mm, much smaller than the height of the `\parbox`! Why is this? What should I do to get the real height of the `\parbox`?

Interestingly, if the `\parbox` is surrounded by a `\frame`, everything works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Insert the lines

```
\showthe\ht\foobox
\showthe\dp\foobox
```

and all will be clear:
The height of `\foobox` is indeed 6.83331pt just as you have found.
The depth, on the other hand, is 36pt.
Notice that boxes have height and depth both, as measured from the baseline of the box.
In this case, this happens because you use `\parbox[t]`. If you switch to `\parbox[b]` things might work more like you expect, at least as far as the height calculation goes. But then, of course, the baseline of the box may not be where you need it to be.

Answer (score 16):

The [`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) package also provides the commands `\totalheightof` and `\settototalheight`, "totalheight" being the sum of height and depth.

Answer (score 8):

It's because of the `[t]` option. It's sets the official `parbox` baseline to the baseline of the first line. Therefore the `height` of the box is the height of the first line. The rest is now part of the official `depth`.

What you need is the so called `totalheight` which is `height`+`width`. There is no primitive for this, therefore there isn't a `\settototalheight`. However, if you already have the material inside a savebox you don't need to use these macros anyway, but can use `\ht`, `\dp` and `\wd` to get the height, depth and width of the saved box.

The `totalheight` can be calculated using the 'calc' package:

```
\usepackage{calc}
%...
\setlength{\fooboxheight}{\ht\foobox+\dp\foobox}
```

or using the eTeX primitive `\dimexpr`:

```
\setlength{\fooboxheight}{\dimexpr\ht\foobox+\dp\foobox}
```

Comment: Actually, the calc package defines `\settototalheight`.

Comment: @lockstep: Thanks, I didn't know that. I rarely use it since I know about the eTeX primitives and `pgfmath`.