# Measuring height of fixed-width text box

Tags: boxes, calculations

Suppose some text is put inside a fixed width box. The text will then continue in vertical direction. How can you measure the total height of that text?

Original text:

```
text text text text text
```

Text in a box constrained to width of `text text`

```
text text
text text
text
```

How long is this?

```
+
|
+
```

Comment: See also the recent question [Why doesn't \settoheight of \parbox work?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11943/2975).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can make such a box and measure it directly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\foo
\begin{document}
\settototalheight\foo{\parbox{3cm}{text text text text text text text text text}}
\the\foo
\end{document}
```