# Table cell overflow

Tags: tables, boxes, tabularx, height

Consider this document example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx,multirow}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=0cm}

\newlength\framewidth
\setlength{\framewidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\framewidth}{-3cm}

\begin{document}
\centering

\fbox{
\begin{tabularx}{\framewidth}{XXX}
\multirow{3}{0.30\framewidth}{\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth, height=1cm]{test}\vspace{0.1cm}\linebreak\sffamily\tiny
subtext\linebreak
more text} &%
\multirow{3}{0.30\framewidth}{\centering\large\textsc{Project name}\linebreak\textbf{Current document, more text, and even more text, still more text}} &%
a \\
& & b \\
& & c \\
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

I've marked with yellow color the text that was overflown out of the cell. Also, if I put everything in a box, and measure that box, it is shorter than actual text contained in the box. Why is that?

[image: Overflown table cell]

Comment: @ipavlic: I changed your code a tiny bit to allow it to compile without the missing image. If you want to use a dummy image in your examples, load the `graphicx` package with the [demo] option, and just use anything you'd like as a placeholder name of the image when including it. See the revision history to check what I have changed.

Comment: @Martin Tapankov: Thanks. I left that in the code in case it was relevant.

Comment: @ipavlic: Just remove such code and recompile to see if the issue is gone. It it isn't, the code isn't relevant. It should be a *minimal* example after all.

Comment: Note that using *only* `X` columns with `tabularx` doesn't make much sense. You can just replace them (or at least the first two) with `p{.333\framewidth}` instead.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: It seems to me that using p{.333\framewidth} yields a table that is around 2 cm wider :/.

Comment: @ipavlic: I think `X` is calculating the column distance in and `p{ }` of course not. Use the calculations in my updated answer to compensate for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `\multirow{3}{...}` for this cell and therefore explicitly requesting three lines, but then you have enough text for four lines. Either change it to `\multirow{4}{...}` and add a `\\` or change the column type to `p{.3\framewidth}`.

Note that AFAIK `\multirow` sets the official height of the content to be only the first line and the rest is then part of the *depth*.

See also the answers to the questions ["Why doesn't \settoheight of \parbox work?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11943/2975) and ["Measuring height of fixed-width text box"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11947/2975) which explain how to measure the correct height for such boxes.

---

In response to the OP's comment:

You could define all three columns as `p` type columns and enter the right side content as one cell, like the others. You can use `\newline` as line break command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx,multirow}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=0cm}

\newlength\framewidth
\setlength{\framewidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\framewidth}{-3cm}

\begin{document}
\centering

\fbox{%
\begin{tabularx}{\framewidth}{p{.3\framewidth}p{.3\framewidth}p{.3\framewidth}}
 \multirow{3}{0.30\framewidth}{%
   \centering
   %\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Images/Logo}%
   \rule{.2\textwidth}{1cm}
   \vspace{0.1cm}\linebreak\sffamily\tiny
   subtext\linebreak
   more text} &%
   \centering\large\textsc{Project name}\linebreak\textbf{Current document, more text, and even more text, still more text}
  &%
  { a \newline b \newline c \newline } \\
\end{tabularx}%
}
\end{document}
```

---

I think the `tabular` environment might be not the best option in this case. Three `minipages` side by side would be better suited:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}


\newlength\framewidth
\setlength{\framewidth}{\textwidth-4\tabcolsep-2\fboxsep}

\begin{document}
\centering

% Horizontal rule for comparison
\hrule\par\bigskip

\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.333\framewidth}
   \centering
   \vspace*{0pt}
   %\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Images/Logo}%
   \rule{.8\textwidth}{1cm}% graphic dummy
   \\[.1cm]\sffamily\tiny
   subtext\linebreak
   more text
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{2\tabcolsep}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.333\framewidth}
   \centering\large\textsc{Project name}\\
   \bfseries Current document, more text, and even more text,
   still more text
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{2\tabcolsep}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.333\framewidth}
   a \\ b \\ c
\end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What if I don't know the contained text in advance? I can't just insert new rows into my source every time that text changes. As for the `p{.3\framewidth}`, that would imply that the `a` row is as high as `Project name...` row. I would prefer that rows `a`, `b` and `c` stretch evenly if necessary to accomodate `multirow`'d `Project name...`.

Comment: @ipavlic: See my updated answer. I think the `minipage` solution is best suited for your application. If this is not so, tell me.