# How to measure the height of a tikz picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, height

I have several graphics (produced by `TikZ`) in my document. They all have different sizes. How do I get the height of each graphic to do some nasty calculations?

**Edit**

I want to access the picture height in the text (not in the picture!), e.g. "The picture above has a height of `\the\tikzheight`."

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    % WHAT HEIGHT DO I HAVE?
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        % help lines
        \draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-0.95,-0.95) grid (4.95,4.95);
        % axis
        \draw[thick,->] (-1,0) -- (5,0);
        \draw[thick,->] (0,-1) -- (0,5);

        % points
        \foreach \Point/\PointLabel in {(1,1)/A, (3,1)/B, (1,4)/P_1, (3,4)/P_1}
        \draw[fill=black] \Point circle (0.05) node[above right] {$\PointLabel$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: hello, What do you want to do at the end ?

Comment: this answer works with your code after suppressing empty lines inside `tikzpicture`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11949/1952

Comment: Let's say I want to save the height `\newdimen\tikzheight` and print it like `\showthe\tikzheight`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it help? It draws the picture and writes its size in its center. Printed values don't consider the `scale` factor. In this case, real height would be 1.5*171.27066pt.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

    % WHAT HEIGHT DO I HAVE?
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        % help lines
        \draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-0.95,-0.95) grid (4.95,4.95);
        % axis
        \draw[thick,->] (-1,0) -- (5,0);
        \draw[thick,->] (0,-1) -- (0,5);
        % points
        \foreach \Point/\PointLabel in {(1,1)/A, (3,1)/B, (1,4)/P_1, (3,4)/P_1}
        \draw[fill=black] \Point circle (0.05) node[above right] {$\PointLabel$};
        \draw let \p1 = ($(current bounding box.north east)-(current bounding box.south west)$) 
          in node[red] at (current bounding box.center) {(\x1,\p1)}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Update:

[Leo Liu's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11949/1952) answer adapted to this particular problem. It uses `calc` package instead of `calc` tikzlibrary.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}

\newsavebox\mytikz
\newlength\tikzheight

\begin{document}

\savebox{\mytikz}{%
    % WHAT HEIGHT DO I HAVE?
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, transform shape]
        % help lines
        \draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-0.95,-0.95) grid (4.95,4.95);
        % axis
        \draw[thick,->] (-1,0) -- (5,0);
        \draw[thick,->] (0,-1) -- (0,5);
        % points
        \foreach \Point/\PointLabel in {(1,1)/A, (3,1)/B, (1,4)/P_1, (3,4)/P_1}
        \draw[fill=black] \Point circle (0.05) node[above right] {$\PointLabel$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\usebox{\mytikz}
\settototalheight\tikzheight{\usebox{\mytikz}}

The picture above has a height of \the\tikzheight.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to print the real height in the text (e.g. below the picture). Something like "The picture above has an height of 250pt."

Comment: @Ignasi : I did not find  `"in node"` in the PGF documentation, could you please tell the page or section number in the manual? Thanks!

Comment: @Sr.Schneider Answer update, I hope it's better now.

Comment: @AlexG The expression is not `in node` but `let ... in` which corresponds to `calc` tikzlibrary. You can start with tutorial "Euclid’s Amber Version of the Elements" (section or chapter 4)