# Is there an option to simulate the drawing of a TikZ pic without really drawing it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

Currently, I draw a TikZ picture with lots of TikZ elements and subelements. To do this, I use TikZ *pic*. Sometimes, I need to know the size of a pic prior to its drawing for the correct positioning. This information comes from its local bounding box. But in order to get this information, I have to draw it, using *opacity = 0*.

Is there an option to *simulate* the drawing of a pic element (or any TikZ element) without having to go via *opacity = 0*?

Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{
            subtikz/.pic={
                \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
            }
        }
        % Simulate pic to get its local bounding box.
        \pic [local bounding box = Subtikz, opacity = 0] {subtikz};
        % Calculate position depending on other input.
        \path let \p1 = (Subtikz.north east), \p2 = (1, 2), \p3 = (3, 4) in coordinate (NorthEast) at ({max(\x1, \x2, \x3)}, \y1);
        % Draw pic taking into account other input.
        \pic at (NorthEast) {subtikz};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can do this with the command `\savebox`. See 2nd part of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307804/123129).

Comment: You can also get the height from the (current bounding box) (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137356/how-can-i-access-the-size-of-a-tikzpictures-bounding-box-outside-the-tikzpictur) but these days I always use a savebox.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I understand correctly, \savebox works for tikzpicture but not for a specific pic in a tikzpicture. While I get the correct tikzpicture's height (px) with @dexteritas suggestion I could not get the pic's height or width with it. Thus, I still have to stick to my approach where the pic is drawn twice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the special `discard` layer after you've set it up with

```
\pgfdeclarelayer{discard}
```

When it is declared as the layer to be used with `pgfonlayer`,
the content will be placed on that layer but since you don't set it with

```
\pgfsetlayers{discard, main}
```

it won't show up in the picture. (Only `discard` works that way, every other name needs to be specified in `\pgfsetlayers`.)

With that setup you can just do

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{discard}
  \pic [local bounding box = Subtikz] {subtikz};
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

This obviously won't work if you want to use the pic as part of another path that should show up but [that can be arranged](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/668356) as well (especially if you don't use any foreground or background code in your pic).

---

I've added a simple `\pgfshowdiscardlayeranyway` command that uses that layer anyway which may be useful for debugging purposes.

Since that layer is not setip with `\pgfsetlayers` it will accumulate and will not be emptied at the start of the next picture which I show off in the code below since I'm just using `\pgfshowdiscardlayeranyway` in a second TikZ picture which then contains your original pic.

This had advantages but maybe it's not desirable, for this I'll add a `discard discard layer` key that can be used as an option to a `tikzpicture` (or a `scope`) to globally empty out the layer. It might be worth to do

```
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={discard discard layer}}
```

to not drag around that layer through out your whole document.

---

As an additional note, the way it is setup now, your discarded pic still contributes to the bounding box in the original picture but *not* if you use the `\pgfshowdiscardlayeranyway` in another picture. (This isn't noticeable in the example below because I added a grid to show the positions better.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfdeclarelayer{discard} % ← declare discard layer
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  discard discard layer/.style={
    execute at end scope=%
      \global\let\pgf@layerbox@discard\pgfutil@voidb@x}}
\newcommand*\pgfshowdiscardlayeranyway{\box\pgf@layerbox@discard}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  % discard discard layer,
  subtikz/.pic={\draw (0, 0) -- (1, 0);}]
\draw[help lines] (-.5,-.5) grid (4.5,.5);

\begin{pgfonlayer}{discard} % ← place on discard layer
  \pic [local bounding box = Subtikz] {subtikz};
\end{pgfonlayer}

% Calculate position depending on other input.
\path let \p1 = (Subtikz.north east),
          \p2 = (1, 2), \p3 = (3, 4) in
  coordinate (NorthEast) at ({max(\x1, \x2, \x3)}, \y1);
% Draw pic taking into account other input.
\pic at (NorthEast) {subtikz};

%\pgfshowdiscardlayeranyway % ← show layer anyway
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-.5,-.5) grid (4.5,.5);
\pgfshowdiscardlayeranyway
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Outpu

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you need to insert content for calculation purposes only, place it in a `\savebox` without actually using it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{
            subtikz/.pic={
                \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
            }
        }
        % Simulate pic to get its local bounding box.
        \savebox{0}{\pic [local bounding box = Subtikz, opacity = 1] {subtikz};}
        % Calculate position depending on other input.
        \path let \p1 = (Subtikz.north east), \p2 = (1, 2), \p3 = (3, 4) in coordinate (NorthEast) at ({max(\x1, \x2, \x3)}, \y1);
        % Draw pic taking into account other input.
        \pic at (NorthEast) {subtikz};
        \usebox{0} % use it anyway (placing it at its original position)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```