# Quotchap editing space

Tags: quotchap

I am using the [quotchap package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/quotchap) and was wondering how to set the height smaller for the quote. As example if you don't have any quote at all or just a short one it could be less high.
Unfortunately I couldn't find the proper solution in the read me pdf of the package just that it is usually about 10cm which they reserve for the quote.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that highlights your issue. It would just make it easier for the community to pick up and get solutions your way. Really, helping us helps you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual:

> It has one optional argument that provides the width of the quotation
>   paragraph. The default is 10cm (approx. 3:94in).

Thus the 10cm are the width and can be changed by e.g. `\begin{savequote}[45mm]...\end{sevequote}`.

The vertical space before the chapter number is determined by

```
\providecommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{2.3\baselineskip}}
```

To change this, you can use e.g.

```
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{0.1\baselineskip}}
```

after loading the package to change the height globally, or before a chapter to change it for that chapter and all following ones. Using another `\renewcommand...` before the next chapter would change the height again, but presumably the authors of the package thought that it might look better if the chapter numbers were issued at the same height regarding the top of the page. If you want variable heigh, you would need to measure the height of each quote (see [Why doesn't \settoheight of \parbox work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11943/6865)) and adapt the `\chapterheadstartvskip` accordingly (if that is really what you want).

Comment: Thank you very much - that is exactly what I wanted!!
I found the width command but I didn't find the other one. Thanks again.